# Multiple audio channels out from skype

Tags: skype, audio-recording

In a group video calling, is it possible to make Skype (or a 3rd party app) split the audio from each caller, so that I can record each caller in it's own track/channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype does not cover that feature. And I think the Skype API is not open enough for adding it.

Since Skype appears as an audio device client to the operating system, without the system knowing anything about the "channels", there is no direct way of creating a utility that sits between Skype and the operating system, splitting the audio streams to different tracks, or channels.